# How can I run background work like alarm on latest android phones

Tags: java, android

I have some task like medicine reminder. Everyday reminder schedule is stored in the SQLite database. Reminders are every day different.

For example

21.02.19 - 08:00, 12:00, 19:00

22.02.19 - 08:30, 12:30, 19:30

...

Minimum android 4.4 (Api 19) 
Target android 9.0 (Api 28)

I read about WorkManager, JobScheduler, JobIntentService, FirebaseJobDispathcer, Alarm manager. There is a lot of API s to do that.

Firstly I tried to check time with interval every minute using alarm manager. But it is not working properly in latest android. There have background restrictions, Doze Mode and standby.  Then I tried JobScheduler but it does not work devices under 21 API. And FirebaseJobDispatcher required google play service, it is not a good idea. Finally, I find WorkManager. But in workmanager and jobscheduler have minimum interval like 15 minutes.

How can I make background service to remind users in specific exact time every day? I am not using the internet, GPS, location. Only get time from SQLite and remind in exact time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a few months ago, I developed medicine reminder app too.

I use 'run the daily job in 0:00AM using [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)' methods to achieve this.

In DailyJob, we have this process.

1. Grab some time information in DB
2. Convert (desired time - now time) into milliseconds. if now time is 00:15AM and desire time is 07:00AM, it will be 24300000ms.
3. Run exact job with converted milliseconds in Step 2.

In Exact job, we display a notification to the user.

I can't attach code because of privacy, but you can achieve the same things.

Comment: 'If you start a new project, you should be using WorkManager instead of this library. You should also start migrating your code from this library to WorkManager. At some point in the future this library will be deprecated. ' I read this from android-job library? How to implement your process in WorkManager?

Comment: Although documentation says 'You should using WorkManager', but WorkManager api has not stable and doesn't provide exact job feature. So, I implemented the process using android-job.

Comment: Good idea! How about latest android versions?

Comment: As I now, DailyJob and ExactJob using AlarmManager in inside of library. So there is background limitation such as Doze. 
Finally i added Doze whitelist when user entered application. there is no proper solution to reduce accuracy for alarm.

Comment: One more question. If I am using background service like chat using socket io with android. Sockets required short connections. And I must reconnect every 5 minutes and protect it from kill.  How can I do that?

Comment: Hmm.. There are two things that come to mind right now. One is background service with ```startForeground()``` methods. Other solution is if situations with a background, disconnect from the socket server. And when someone sends a message through a socket server, pass that message through the FCM. But I think there are other good ways to do it, so it would be better to ask for another question.

Comment: Great. In my situation. Can I use startForeground to make reminder? If yes, how?

Comment: Implement queue table for desire time. and every 1 minute, compare time and table and firing alarm. but it will drain much battery. I think this solution isn't proper solution.

Comment: For apps targeting Android 33+, apps using the Exact Alarm Permission will only be allowed on Google Play if the app is a Calendar app or an Alarm Clock app.  See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9934569#:~:text=Effective%20July%2031%2C%202023